# no such module PanModal - Xcode ios app swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, xcode11

I'm a very beginner in iOS developement (I'm coming from Android).
I'm taking back a project from another developer.
I can't build the project.

I already applied what I saw through SO like `pod install`, double check if no duplicate of .xcodeproject.
Yes I open the .xcworkspace and not .xcodeproj.

when I run `pod install`:

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

I already tried to delete the `Pods` folder, then pod setup `pod install` and open the .xcworkspace. Didn't make it.

There is my `Podfile`:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.1'

target 'project_name' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  workspace './project_name.xcworkspace/'
  project './project_name.xcodeproj'

  # Pods for project_name

  target 'project_nameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `pod 'PanModal'` to your podfile and run `pod install`

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.1'

target 'project_name' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'PanModal'

  # Pods for project_name

  target 'project_nameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: ok. now I have some others missing. They come after one by one. How can I list them in one time to add them all ?

Comment: If you know all the pods than add all at the same time in `podfile` and run the same command otherwise version control can rescue you in this case. Last option if both are not available is to add the pod as Xcode show the error

Comment: I don't know all the pods. What do you mean by the version control? I used the last option, add the pod after each error, build, error, add pod, build, error, add pod...

Comment: Version control keeps the history of each change you made to file. The most popular one is Git. If the project has enabled Git than you can `checkout` your `podfile` to an older version which have all of the pods. This would have made your life easier.